# How to get MvcResult when unit testing POST with MultipartFile

Tags: spring-boot, multipart, spring-test, mockmvc

When i'm testing just trivial POST-requests, i can get MvcResult and get something from it:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/register")
                .contentType(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(new Gson().toJson(request)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn();
Long tempId = Long.valueOf(JsonPath.read(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), "$.id").toString());
```

But when i'm using MultipartFile, i can only use MockMvcRequestBuilders and only check expectations.

```
MockMultipartFile filePart = new MockMultipartFile(
                "file",
                "file.jpg",
                "image/jpeg", file);
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/api/loadfile")
                .file(filePart)
                .param("json", json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

How can i get MvcResult with multipart POST after request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.andReturn();` right after `.andExpect()` like you did it in the trivial POST example.

Calling `mockMvc.perform()` returns a `ResultActions` object independent of any HTTP method or request.

The following example works with Spring Boot 2.3.0:

```
byte[] file = new byte[10];
MockMultipartFile filePart = new MockMultipartFile(
  "file", "file.jpg", "image/jpeg", file);

MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/api/loadfile")
  .file(filePart)
  .param("json", "json"))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andReturn();
```